# Cross-referencing Issue in ConTeXt

Tags: cross-referencing, context, interaction

Perhaps this is a silly question, but I’m learning to use ConTeXt and I haven’t been able to get `\reference`, `\goto`, `\in`, and `\at` to work as I want.

The problem is that, when I have a `\reference` and use it with `\goto` or `\in`, instead of taking me to the element I referenced, it takes me to the start of the page (the correct page, but not the element). I tried setting `\setupinteraction{state=start, page=no}`, but `\goto`, `\at`, and `\in` still take me to the start of the page. Can anyone help me understand why this is happening and how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems that you need `focus=standard`. Try

```
\setupinteraction
  [state=start,
   focus=standard]
```

Note also that brackets are used here, not braces.